# Rewrite the equation as a system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone explain the steps to getting this solution. I am unsure how its possible to add the matrices of different sizes.

$(\sin(t)){y}'''-2{y}''+{y}'+3y=e^t$

The solution is supposedly:

$\begin{bmatrix} {y}'\\ {y}''\\ {y}''' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &-1 &0 \\ 0 &0 &2 \\ -3 &-1 &2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ e^t \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: yes the $sin(t)$ is really there. i'm not sure about the typos this is what was given to me

Comment: I think all they are doing is reducing the 3-rd order ODE to a system of first order ODEs. It appears that there are some errors in the problem statement and the reduction (which is not a solution). The reduced system is in no way going to lead to a solution for the stated problem as it is currently written! I can write a solution showing how the reduction is done, but I will correct items that appear to be in error. Let me know if you want to see that.

Comment: that would be wonderful. I guess ignore the solution (system of equations) that i put and only use the original equation, I know the original equation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are writing the third-order linear ODE as a system of first order equations, but there are some problems in what is written.

We have: $x_1 = y$, so

- $x'_1 = y' = x_2$
- $x'_2 = y'' = x_3$
- $x'_3 = y''' = 2y'' - y' - 3y + 3^t = -3x_1 -x_2 + 2 x_3 + e^t$

In matrix form, we can write this system as:

$$X'(t) = \begin{bmatrix} {x_1}'\\ {x_2}'\\ {x_3}' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {y}'\\ {y}''\\ {y}''' \end{bmatrix} = AX(t) + F(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &0 &1 \\ -3 &-1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} {x_1}\\ {x_2}\\ {x_3} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ e^t \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: also, what happens to the sin? you think its not supposed to be there?

Comment: If it is there, this process does not work. Also, some of the constants in your solution were not correct, so something went wrong with the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could write that 3rd order equation as a system of 1st order equations by introducing two more dependent variables, say $g(t)$ and $h(t)$, as

$$ g=y'$$
$$ h=y''.$$
Thus,

$$ \sin(t) h'-h+g+3y=e^{t} $$
$$ g=y'$$
$$ g'=h. $$
Now you have three coupled first order linear equations in $y$, $g$ and $h$.

Is this what you're looking for?

Cheers,

Paul Safier